# Given a string, replace " is " with " is not "

Tags: java, strings

> Given a string, if string has " is "(before and after space) in it:
>   replace it with "is not".
>
> Example:
>
> - Original: This is a string
> - New: This is not a string

I am implementing it using string/char arrays. Is there any better way to solve this question? I have a feeling that it can be solved with a regular expression. Can anyone suggest some better/different approach to solving this question?

```
/**
 * 
 *
 * Given a string. If string has " is "(before and after space) in it: replace it with "is not"
 * e.g.,
 * Original : This is a string
 * New : This is not a string
 */
public class ReplaceString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "This is bag";
        replaceIs(s);

    }

    public static void replaceIs(String s) {
        /* Find number of "is" in string to get length of new array*/

        String wordToFind = " is ";
        Pattern word = Pattern.compile(wordToFind);
        Matcher match = word.matcher(s);
        int counterOfWord = 0;
        while (match.find()) {
            ++counterOfWord;
        }
        int lengthOfNewArray = s.length() + (counterOfWord * 4);
        char[] originalCharArray = s.toCharArray();
        char[] newCharArray = new char[lengthOfNewArray];

        /* Parse String from the end and if " is " encounters, replace it with " is not" */
        int indexInNewArray = lengthOfNewArray;
        int i = originalCharArray.length - 1;
        while ( i >= 0 ) {
            if (originalCharArray[i] == ' ' && originalCharArray[i - 1] == 's' && originalCharArray[i - 2] == 'i' && originalCharArray[i - 3] == ' ' ) {

                newCharArray[indexInNewArray - 1] = ' ';
                newCharArray[indexInNewArray - 2] = 't';
                newCharArray[indexInNewArray - 3] = 'o';
                newCharArray[indexInNewArray - 4] = 'n';
                newCharArray[indexInNewArray - 5] = ' ';
                newCharArray[indexInNewArray - 6] = 's';
                newCharArray[indexInNewArray - 7] = 'i';
                newCharArray[indexInNewArray - 8] = ' ';
                i = i - 4;
                indexInNewArray = indexInNewArray - 8;

            } else {
                newCharArray[indexInNewArray - 1] = originalCharArray[i];
                --indexInNewArray;
                --i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(newCharArray));
    }
}
```

Comment: You already use Regex and Matcher, so why not using `String::replaceAll()`?

Comment: If we want to implment it without using String::replaceAll()

Comment: If you want do all the low level stuff yourself you should use  a different language. This kind of procedural processing will not make you a good Java programmer...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I disagree. It is educational to do this kind of lower level programming, because it forces you to create an algorithm, make you think about performance, etc. etc. I would actually also not use `Regex` to make it more interesting

Comment: @Qurrat Try to solve it without any `Regex`, just using `char[]` logic. The easiest wat to construct the new `String` is by using `StringBuilder.append()`

Comment: @RobAu This is only true for *precedural unmanaged* languages. But in programming languages with *memory management* and *higher programming paradigms* you should better train how to correctly *use the languages library* and how to *correctly apply principles of OOP and FP*.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest:

```
String replaceIs(String s) {
    return s.replace(" is ", " is not ");
}
```

In Oracle Java 8, this uses a regular expression internally, but in Java 9 it will be implemented with a more efficient algorithm.

By the way, will your code throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when your string starts with a space?